# Batch file doesn't close after START

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a batch file having the following structure:

```
cd "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\data-integration\"
start /B "" Pan.bat /file:"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc.ktr" /level:Basic > D:\abc.log
start /B "" Pan.bat /file:"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\xyz.ktr" /level:Basic > D:\xyz.log
EXIT
```

Here, my 2 start commands execute successfully, but the window that opens on startup does not close by itself. I have tried `EXIT /B 0` and other such options as well, but the console does not disappear. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should use `Call` with a `.bat` file instead of `Start`

Comment: I want to execute these 2 statements in parallel. Using 'Call' does not execute the commands in parallel. So, this is of no use to me.

Comment: Don't use `CD` just prepend `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\data-integration\ ` to `Pan.bat` instead or use `Start`'s **`/D`** option. That said, you're not actually `Start`ing `Pan.bat` you're `Start`ing `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Just removed the CD part and appended it to START commands, but still window does not close.

Comment: Look at my last sentence it may explain. If you're running an internal `cmd` command or a batch file then the command processor is run with the `/K` option to `cmd.exe`. This means that the window will remain after the command has been run. You may therefore have to run `cmd.exe` with it's `/C` option and your script and parameters bolted onto it. Additionally, I see no need for the `/B` option, you could just use `/MIN` for a relatively short duration batch file.

Comment: I suggest to change the topic title by something like "Batch file don't close after START"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `/B` switch on `start`. This does not start a silent process - I believe you'd need to search SO for a VBS approach to do that.

It may suit your purpose to change the `/B` switch to `/min`.

Comment: Using /b does not open 2 separate windows for each process, instead both are executed in the same window. So, if I remove /b, 2 windows are opened.

Comment: Yes - but it appears to hold the current window open, which is apparently what you want to avoid.

Comment: So, you say that instead of /B, I put /min in both the START commands?

Comment: No. Now I get two windows, after the complete execution, the two windows still remain opened.

Comment: Do you end your `pan.bat` files with an `exit` statement?

Comment: Where to add this? Pan.bat executes the .ktr file present in the argument.